# Multiple request ids

Tags: facebook, request

In the request 2.0 documentation, they mention that the app can get request_ids, which is a comma delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon.

I was wondering if someone can give an example when multiple ids will arrive. Usually for each request the user sees a single notification so how come several requests might be combined to a single call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All request are grouped in left pane, showing the number of them next to app name, aren't they? It seems only logical that you get them all if you click on the app name there.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that Facebook groups requests on the notifications list as well. So if several users invite you, all requests will arrived to the app on a single call.